# conjunction: is "and" necessary?

Tags: conjunctions

Is **and** necessary in the following?

> Such criminal activity is difficult to track, **and** even more so in the Internet.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Probably! It links the coordination of the two AdjPs "difficult to track" and "even more so on the Internet" functioning as PC of "be", (note that "so" = "difficult to track"). You could if you wished replace "and" with a dash.

Comment: You don't need the "and" if you replace the comma with a semicolon. "Such criminal activity is difficult to track; even more so in the Internet"

Comment: It's fine as it is in *informal* writing too. (The omitted **it is** is assumed to be present.)

Comment: Is it natural to omit "and"?

Comment: @Apollyon, No, it is best retained. "So" acts as a pro-predicative here. In full it would be "Such criminal activity is [difficult to track], and [even more difficult to track in the Internet]. The bracketed elements are a coordination of adjective phrases functioning as subjective predicative complement.